# how to use unique value for primary key of two table in phpMyAdmin -sql ? (use in php)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 table like this:

1-private_messages table:

```
messageId  | message
--------------------
1          |  text1
4          |  text4
```

2-public_messages table:

```
messageId  |  message 
----------------------
2          |  text2
3          |  text3
5          |  text5
```

in two table , messageId column is primaryKey

now I want that these two column be auto increment and has a unique Id in two table like shown above.

now when I want to insert a row in one of tables , I had to find max Id of each table and compare them to find max of them. then increase that and insert new row.

I want know, is there any better or automatic way that when I insert new row, database do that automatically?

thanks

Comment: Don't do it that way: have a single table for all messages, and add a public/private flag column on that table. That way, you can set a simple auto_increment id on the single table

Comment: thank for your help.but this is just a part of those tables. public table has about 20 other columns but private has about 3 other columns and do that work cause vary waste disk space

Comment: @Sadegh so have an annexe table for al the other columns... or make private message ids even and public message ids odd

Comment: this is a good idea to have  an annex table. about your second way how to odd and even them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain unique numbers in MySQL with a programming pattern like the following.

First create a table for the sequence. It has an auto-increment field and nothing else.

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (
    sequence_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_id`)
)
```

Then when you need to insert a unique number into one of your tables, use something like these queries:

```
INSERT INTO sequence () VALUES ();
DELETE FROM sequence WHERE sequence_id < LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO private_messages (messageID, message)
                      VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'the message');
```

The second INSERT is guaranteed to use a unique sequence number. This guarantee holds even if you have dozens of different client programs connected to your database. That's the beauty of AUTO_INCREMENT.

The second query (DELETE) keeps the table from getting big and wasting space. We don't care about any rows in the table except for the most recent one.

**Edit**. If you're using php, simply issue the three queries one after the other using three calls to `mysqli_query()` or the equivalent method in the MySQL interface you have chosen for your program.

All that being said, beware of false economy.  Don't forget that storage on Amazon S3 costs USD 0.36 per year per gigabyte. And that's the most expensive storage. The "wasted" storage cost for putting your two kinds of tables into a single table will likely amount to a few dollars. Troubleshooting a broken database app in production will cost thousands of dollars. Keep it simple!

Comment: this seems a good way . but I use database in php. can I execute them in php?. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use flag like 1 for private messages and 0 for public in a single table , so it is easy to insert and easy to fetch and compare....

```
messageId | message | flag
---------------------------
   1 | text1  | 1
   2 | text2  | 0
   3 | text3  | 0
   4 | text4  | 1
   5 | text5  | 0
```

Comment: thanks but this is not a good way for my work. read second comment of my question !

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this automatically that I'm aware of.

You might be able to write a function in the DB to make it happen, I don't recommend it.

Mark Baker's suggestion, to have a single `messages` table and a public/private flag sounds like the best way to go if you absolutely need IDs to be unique across both types of messages.